# Is the determinant an analytic function?

Tags: determinant, analyticity

I came accross a paper stating that the analytical property of determinants of complex matrices allows us to use some theorem for analytic functions. I am not able to confirm this since I am not sure the determinant is an analytic function / which analytical property is meant.

So, my question is: Can the determinant be seen as an analytic function or does it have some analytical property?

Thanks in advance,

Frederik

Comment: The determinant of a matrix is polynomial in its entries, so is analytic.

Comment: A determinant is a sum of products, it will inherit the properties of the factors.

Comment: An analytic function... with respect to which variable(s)?

Comment: Thank you, guys. It is actually very obvious now :)